# localStorage add element to list

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, local-storage

I'm creating a dynamic list witch uses `localstorage` to save `json` array data and I've meet problem.

In firebug it shows this error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected keyword  
var cli=JSON.parse(table[i]);
```

this is my jquery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var count = 0,
table = localStorage.getItem('table');
table = JSON.parse(table);
if(table == null) {
    table = []; 
}

jQuery('.add_rem').on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(jQuery(this).hasClass('remove')) {
      count -= 1;
    }else {
      count += 1;
    }     

      if(jQuery(this).hasClass('remove')){
          if(count == 0) {
            jQuery('.list li.empty').show();
            localStorage.clear();
          }

              jQuery("#"+localStorage.getItem('id')).removeClass('remove');
              jQuery('.panel2 a span').text('('+ localStorage.getItem('count') +')');
              jQuery(localStorage.getItem(jQuery(this).attr('id'))).remove()
              localStorage.removeItem('id');

      } else {
          jQuery('.list li.empty').hide();

          var clipelements = JSON.stringify({
              'id': jQuery(this).closest('tr').attr('id'),
              'elementlink': jQuery(this).closest('tr').find('.link').attr('href'),
              'photo': jQuery(this).closest('tr').find('.photo').attr('src'),
              'name': jQuery(this).closest('tr').find('.name').text()
          })

          table.push(clipelements);
          localStorage.setItem('table', JSON.stringify(clipelements));
          localStorage.setItem('count', count);



        for(var i in table){
            var cli = JSON.parse(table[i]);
            jQuery("#"+cli.id ).find(".add_rem").addClass('remove');    
        jQuery('#hp-content .wrapper .list').append('<li id="'+cli.id+'"><a href="'+ cli.elementlink+'"><img src="'+ cli.photo +'"/><br />'+ cli.name +'</a></li>');
        }


        jQuery('.panel2 a span').text('('+ localStorage.getItem('count') +')');
      }
})  
if(localStorage.count > 0){
        jQuery('#hp-content .wrapper .list li.empty').hide();
        for(var i in table){
            var cli = JSON.parse(table[i]);
            jQuery("#"+cli.id ).find(".add_rem").addClass('remove');    
            jQuery('#hp-content .wrapper .list').append('<li id="'+cli.id+'"><a href="'+ cli.elementlink+'"><img src="'+ cli.photo +'"/><br />'+ cli.name +'</a></li>');
        }
if(!localStorage.getItem('count')) {    

} else {
    jQuery('.panel2 a span').text('('+ localStorage.getItem('count') +')');
}

}
if(!localStorage.getItem('count')) {    

} else {
    jQuery('.panel2 a span').text('('+ localStorage.getItem('count') +')');
}
})
```

this is the string before JSON.parse:

```
"{\"id\":\"13\",\"elementlink\":\"pl/13/zadlo-sciezne/\",\"photo\":\"images/pl/brak.gif\",\"name\":\"żądło ścięźne / kk\"}"
```

and after JSON.parse

```
{"id":"13","elementlink":"pl/13/zadlo-sciezne/","photo":"images/pl/brak.gif","name":"żądło ścięźne / kk"}
```

I want this script to store elements in `JSON` array and display them in unsorted list but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I'm not the jQuery programmer so i think this is my biggest problem.

Comment: From the error you are receiving, it looks as though you have a reserved word in your JSON string `unexpected keyword`. I don't think this is a jQuery issue. Can you post the raw string value that it's trying to parse?

Comment: @RobM. i've added string (array) at the bottom of my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `JSON.parse` too many times - specifically the line that says:

```
var cli = JSON.parse(table[i]);
```

is wrong - it should probably just be `var cli = table[i]`.

As it is, you're trying to pass an already parsed string back through the JSON parser.

Comment: it worked but after page refresh the second loop `for` displays over 100 elements when only one is added